# "#define bool bool" says QtCreator when I hover bool - I tracked that into boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost

I noticed that `bool` is highlighted in different color than other types in QtCreator:

[image: image description]

This occurs only when including certain headers, eventually I tracked it to `<boost/asio.hpp>`. QtCreator's code inspector doesn't seem to be able to track the definition manually. The boost version I use is Boost 1.59.

Is there any purpose for that? I don't really mind it but it's rather strange to define anything to the same thing, more than a `bool`.

Comment: Does `Bool x = true;` compile in your code (With a capital)?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman No, "`Bool does not name a type`". Why would you think so?

Comment: I thought it's undefined behavior when defining a macro with the name of a keyword in C++. Not sure if the fact that the macro's value equals its name makes a difference here...

Comment: It can potentially be useful to protect against some old C header redefining `bool` (`#ifndef bool #define bool char` would cause "interesting" issues) but I'm not sure what it's doing in boost.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, the fact that it it tracks into reputable library such as boost is what surprised me and made me post about it. If it was in our internal sources, I'd just ask and probably delete it after consulting it with others. But it might be some forgotten code or whatever in boost sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I searched the Boost 1.59 code to see if I could find either: `#define bool bool` or `#include <stdbool.h>` but I ended up not finding them so it could be in these files but it might very well be somewhere else.

---

> Is there any purpose for that? I don't really mind it but it's rather strange to define anything to the same thing, more than a bool.

Imagine the code containing something like:

```
#define bool int
// The next line would change the previous definition
#define bool bool
```

then there is:

```
#ifndef bool
#elif bool
#endif
// etc..
```

which would be a really ugly way of trying to port a C program (considering redefining keywords is not allowed in C++).

---

This is probably coming from an include of stdbool.h. which contains this exact content ([atleast on clang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html)). I personally think this is either a bug in the ide/highlighter/parser or there is a file which includes this header/code.

If you are not getting a warning at these settings it is very likely this code is not actually being used and it is just the parsing being bad:

- [Level 1: C4005 warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231853(v=vs.60).aspx) (VS)
- -Wkeyword-macro (clang)

Not sure for GCC -Wall doesn't seem to pick up on it.

Comment: I searched through the current boost sources, and couldn't find `#define bool bool` anywhere either.