# Defining something to itself in C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, self-reference

I ran into these lines:

```
#define bool  bool
#define false false
#define true  true
```

I don't think I need to say more than "wtf?", but just to be clear: What is the point of defining something to itself?

The lines come from [clang stdbool.h](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html)

Comment: Just curious: where have you seen this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797609/why-do-major-compilers-use-typedef-for-stdint-h-but-use-define-for-stdbool-h

Comment: Same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038583/define-bool-bool-says-qtcreator-when-i-hover-bool-i-tracked-that-into-boost

Comment: That basically just stops macro expansion.  Recursive macro references are detected, and block further expansion.

Comment: @rsp that's a C++ link, not C.

Comment: So that you can feature-test with `#ifdef`. Note that the code you are looking at is only for C++, and specifically gcc extensions to old versions of the C++ standard.

Comment: @rici Are you saying that I should retag?

Comment: @klutt: that is up to you; I'm just putting the cited code in context. Observe the #ifndef __cplusplus / #else conditionals

Comment: @rici If I should retag or not does not seem to be a matter of opinion to me. That's why I'm asking for the answer. :)

Comment: @klutt: If you ask the question w.r.t. C, the answer is "that code is incompatible with what the standard requires of stdbool.h" (and so if you have a stdbool.h which performs those assignments, it is not conformant). See section 7.18. If, on the other hand, you ask the question w.r.t. to the current C++ standard, you get a different reason for the definitions to be invalid (keywords are not allowed to be used as macro names, and `cstdbool` is not allowed to define those macros. 17.5.4.3.2 & 18.10.3). But if you asked w.r.t. a very old C++ version, you might get the answer you accepted.

Comment: @klutt: So my opinion is that you must specify the context in which you are asking the question, but that both C and C++ contexts are valid (but different) questions.

Comment: Also, if this question is not specifically about bool, true and false, but rather the general question in the title, then it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315475/why-define-a-macro-with-the-same-name-and-content-in-c/42317302#42317302

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C and C++ standards explicitly allow that (and requires that there is no infinite expansion)

BTW, function-like recursive (or [self-refential](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html)) macros are even more useful:

```
#define puts(X) (nblines++,puts(X))
```

<sup>(the inner `puts`  is a call to the standard `puts` function; the macro "overloads" such further calls by counting `nblines`)</sup>

Your define could be useful, e.g. with later constructs like `#ifdef true`, and it can't be a simple <strike>`#define true`</strike> because that would "erase" every further use of `true`, so it has to be exactly`#define true true`.

Comment: To add to this, it does not interfere with otherwise using the tokens in the code.  If it had just done `#define true` to allow the for `#ifdef true`, then you could not, say, use `true` as the name of a variable.

Comment: I must say I don't fully see the use. Why not simply use `#define true` instead of `#define true true`?

Comment: @klutt Because then all uses of `true` would be erased. With `#define true true`, you can do the macro test and still use `true` as if there never was a macro defined over it.

Comment: Quibble: Neither C nor C++ standards allow `#define bool bool`, specifically, except that you could do it in C if you don't `#include <stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 7):

It allows the user code to conditionally compile based on whether those macros are or aren't defined:

```
#if defined(bool)
    /*...*/
#else
    /*...*/
#endif
```

It basically saves you from having to pollute the global namespace with yet another name (like `HAVE_BOOL`), provided that the implementation lets its users know that *iff* it provides a `bool`, it will also provide a macro with the same name that expands to it (or the implementation may simply use this internally for its own preprocessor conditionals).

Answer (score 4):

It is called self referential Macros.

According to [gcv](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html) reference :

> A self-referential macro is one whose name appears in its definition.
> Recall that all macro definitions are rescanned for more macros to
> replace. If the self-reference were considered a use of the macro, it
> would produce an infinitely large expansion. To prevent this, the
> self-reference is not considered a macro call. It is passed into the
> preprocessor output unchanged.

Reference example :

> One common, useful use of self-reference is to create a macro which expands to itself. If you write
>
> `#define EPERM EPERM`
>
> then the macro EPERM expands to EPERM. Effectively, it is left alone
> by the preprocessor whenever it’s used in running text. You can tell
> that it’s a macro with ‘#ifdef’. You might do this if you want to
> define numeric constants with an enum, but have ‘#ifdef’ be true for
> each constant.

Comment: I can understand that use, that a self-referential macro would terminate on such occasion. What I could not understand at first was the use of writing this variant as actual code.